# Acoustically transparent speaker fabric

Tags: sound, speakers

I would like to find an acoustically transparent material for speakers  and am looking for something with an interesting elegant texture.  I am wondering if raw silk is acoustically transparent?  Or does anyone have another source or idea?  Linen? Just  I am looking for an eggshell color or vanilla. A little stretch would be desired as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether there are any naturally occurring acoustically transparent fabrics, I think the answer is no.

There are plenty of synthetic fabrics that are manufactured to have acoustically transparent properties.  Here's [a good start](https://www.google.com/search?q=acoustically%20transparent%20fabric%20site:www.avsforum.com).